# Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler while compiling a GWT project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compiler-errors

Whenever I try to compile any of my GWT application the compilation fails with the error message "Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler". This problem started after I made some changes to the path and classpath environment variables while installing Tomcat, I don't know whether these changes caused the problem. I tried to reinstall GWT plugin but all in vain. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Eclipse 4.3 and GWT SDK 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Run As > Run Configurations`, delete the current configuration by clicking on the X top left. Apply and close. Now, `Run As > Web application`. A default configuration will be created.

If you have any VM arguments, copy them before doing the steps above.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. But I didn't understand how the old web app configurations got deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Check things as mentioned in below snapshots:

check whether `Main class` is having value `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode` or not.

Go To Run Configuration >

[image]

Go To Project Properties > Build Path

Check whether GWT SDK is installed properly or not

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to create new launch configurations somehow the old ones got deleted.

Comment: It will start working after putting value of `Main Class` as shown in above snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating maven or ant scripts to build outside eclipse.

This way other developers in your team, that maybe don't use eclipse can also build/run the application.

Answer (score 1):

set the "classpath" environment variable  = `%gwt_installed_dir%`

[image: "classpath" environment variable = %gwt_installed_dir%]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem on an old GWT project that was using GWT version 2.4.0 rather than the current 2.8.2. I think older versions of GWT run with legacy/classic development mode. They run the main class in com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode found in gwt-dev.jar.

The error is actually what it says it is. DevMode exists in gwt-dev.jar. You’re missing gwt-dev.jar somewhere in your classpath. You either need to add it as a maven dependency in your pom.xml and then update your maven dependencies like so:

1. In pom.xml:

```js
<properties>
    <!-- this should be whatever version you are using -->
    <gwt.version>2.4.0</gwt.version>  
</properties>


<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
 <version>${gwt.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Update dependencies.

In Eclipse, right click project → maven → “update project...” → tick ‘force update of snapshot/releases’ (just cause you want to be thorough. It’s probably not necessary in this case though). → press OK button.

OR check that you have gwt-dev.jar somewhere in your classpath:

1. In Eclipse, right click project → build path → configure build path → libraries tab → make sure you either have the GWT SDK added as a library, or that gwt-dev.jar exists somewhere in your maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Run Configuration > Arguments. They are not updated automatically when you make changes to  classpath. Make sure your main class is referenced correctly in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in IntelliJ and following steps solved my problem.

1. (In IntelliJ) Go to File --> Project Structure --> Facets (Under project settings)
2. If GWT has set for web facet remove it

[image]

After removing this GWT facet my project compile and run without a problem.